# How to get last 5 weeks of data from user input date

Tags: sql-server

I am not able to get count in weekwise i.e 7 days shipped orders to be one week, please check my query as follows:

```
Declare @CurrentDate nvarchar(50);
SET @CurrentDate='2012-07-25'

BEGIN 

;WITH DateList AS
(
    SELECT  DATEADD(WEEK, 0, CONVERT(DATETIME, @CurrentDate)) AS CreateDateTime, 1 AS Cnter
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(WEEK, -1, CreateDateTime), DateList.Cnter + 1
    FROM DateList
    WHERE DateList.Cnter  < 5
)
SELECT  DateList.CreateDateTime AS ShipWeek, COALESCE(Temp.TotalCount, 0) AS TotalCount
FROM DateList
LEFT JOIN  
(
    SELECT  COUNT(Id) TotalCount
        ,DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19000101',CreatedDateTime),'19000101') AS ShipWeek
    FROM ShipmentDetail 
    WHERE CreatedDateTime
    BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-30,@CurrentDate) AND @CurrentDate
    GROUP BY  DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19000101',CreatedDateTime),'19000101') 
) Temp
    ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateList.CreateDateTime, 112) = Temp.ShipWeek
END
```

Result Table is as follows:

```
ShipWeek                TotalCount
2012-07-25 00:00:00.000 0
2012-07-18 00:00:00.000 0
2012-07-11 00:00:00.000 0
2012-07-04 00:00:00.000 0
2012-06-27 00:00:00.000 0
```

please give me the exact solution.

If I enter  current date as like:

```
SET @CurrentDate='2012-07-30'
```

then result table will give data like:

```
ShipWeek                TotalCount
2012-07-30 00:00:00.000 0
2012-07-23 00:00:00.000 1406
2012-07-16 00:00:00.000 0
2012-07-09 00:00:00.000 0
2012-07-02 00:00:00.000 0
```

why I am not getting if I enter current date like `'2012-07-27'`

Answer (score 2):

It gets much easier if you work with range rather than truncate date to wanted precision. I've changed cte to produce range and removed derived table. Now the query might use indexes. Oh, and I'm unsure about addition condition that narrows CreatedDateTime to last 30 days - first week will lose some shipments.

```
Declare @CurrentDate datetime
SET @CurrentDate='2012-07-25'
;WITH DateList AS
(
    SELECT  DATEADD(WEEK, 0, CONVERT(DATETIME, @CurrentDate)) AS StartRange, 
            DATEADD(WEEK, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, @CurrentDate)) AS EndRange, 
            1 AS Cnter
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(WEEK, -1, StartRange), 
            DATEADD(WEEK, -1, EndRange), 
            DateList.Cnter + 1
    FROM DateList
    WHERE DateList.Cnter  < 5
)
SELECT  DateList.StartRange AS ShipWeek, 
        COALESCE(count(ShipmentDetail.CreatedDateTime), 0) AS TotalCount
FROM DateList
LEFT JOIN ShipmentDetail
    ON DateList.StartRange <= ShipmentDetail.CreatedDateTime
   AND DateList.EndRange > ShipmentDetail.CreatedDateTime
   AND ShipmentDetail.CreatedDateTime 
       BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-30,@CurrentDate) 
                   AND @CurrentDate
GROUP BY DateList.StartRange;
```

[Sql Fiddle with example is this way](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e250/6).